# Using cin.ignore() to skip over 2 spaces

Tags: c++, cin

I figured out how to use cin.ignore() to ignore until the first space. Example would be

```
cout << "Enter your name: ";
cin.ignore(256, ' ');
```

If you enter John Smith, it only reads Smith. But lets say someone wanted to do first, middle, and last name? Like John Doe Smith? Is there a way to ignore until the second whitespace?

EDIT: To clarify, I need each part of the name in a separate variable, not the whole line.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want the user to enter their full name? You should use `std::getline()` to read, and then manipulate the read string as needed.

Comment: To clarify, I want to store each part under its own variable. What I'm trying to do is read a file that's written like

First Middle Last

Comment: What about Victor Isaac Von Doom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `ignore`.  `cin` stops reading at whitespace by default.

```
using namespace std;

string firstName = "";
string middleName = "";
string lastName = "";

cin >> firstName;
cin >> middleName;
cin >> lastName;
```

And as advised above, it is much safer not to ignore input.  Use `std::getline()` instead.

Comment: I didn't even think about that, I totally forgot! Thanks!